# How to get a part of a string according to the part's position (int)?

Tags: java, android, string, split

If you have a String with values that are separated by commas like this:

```
String s = "zero, number one, two, three, number four, five";
```

And you are given a number between 0 and 5 like this:

```
int i = 3;
```

Then how would you get the matching value so that the new string will contain "three" like this:

```
String newString = "three";
```

*The method should work for an unlimited amount of random words in the string.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your string contains commas, you can split that string by commas into an array. Now you can use the number 3 as an index to your tokenized array.

For example:

```
//s is your string as you mentioned above
String [] tokenized=s.split(",");
//i is your number 3 as you mentioned above
System.out.println(tokenized[i]);
```

Comment: See my comment to a previous answer as to why this is incorrect.

Comment: I saw your comments. I don't think there is a problem. He can create some validation conditions. Not so serious problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function like:

```
String getString(String data, int position) {
    return data.split(",")[position];
}
```

And call it like,

```
String s = "zero, number one, two, three, number four, five";
String newString = getString(s, 3);
```

Comment: Won't work with the OP's original string. First, this code fails to check whether there are actually at least "position" entries; It will throw an exception if not, or if the user inputs a negative number. Second, the regex passed to split() is wrong. If you pass "3" to the function, it will return " three" (note the leading space), not "three".